# can't add array values in mysql

Tags: php

```
<input type="number" min="0" name="option1_mark">
<input type="number" min="0" name="option2_mark">
<input type="number" min="0" name="option3_mark">
<input type="number" min="0" name="option4_mark">
```

I have these 4 field. When the user fills any of these fields, its values should get stored in an array.

```
$option_marks=array();
if(isset($_POST['option_marks'])){
$option_marks[0] = $_POST['option1_mark'];
$option_marks[1] = $_POST['option2_mark'];
$option_marks[2] = $_POST['option3_mark'];
$option_marks[3] = $_POST['option4_mark']; 
}
```

Now i want to store its values in database inside this if block.

```
if($result){
    foreach($choice as $option => $value){
        if($value != ""){
            if($correct_choice == $option){
                $is_correct = 1;
            }else{
                $is_correct = 0;
            }
        


            //Second Query for Choices Table
            $query = "INSERT INTO options (";
            $query .= "question_number,choice,correct,mark)";
            $query .= " VALUES (";
            $query .=  "'{$question_number}','{$value}','{$is_correct}','{$option_marks}'";
            $query .= ")";
```

But it stores 0 in mark column. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be simplified by setting the name of the HTML inputs to an array like so:

```
<input type="number" min="0" name="option_marks[]">
<input type="number" min="0" name="option_marks[]">
<input type="number" min="0" name="option_marks[]">
<input type="number" min="0" name="option_marks[]">
```

Currently, after submitting your form, you are checking to see if the named field `option_marks` isset - as there is no field on your form with that name, the code inside the if statement is being skipped over. So you're effectively passing the empty `$option_marks` array (set above the isset check) to your DB.

Now you can just set your array like so:

```
$option_marks = isset($_POST["option_marks"]) ? $_POST["option_marks"] : array();
```

Without seeing the code for `$results` or the `$choice` array it's difficult to see what's going on - but by my understanding, you wish to insert individual marks into the database - as opposed to the whole array for every option? If that's the case, something like this should work:

```
$counter = 0;

if($result){
    foreach($choice as $option => $value){
        if($value != ""){
            if($correct_choice == $option){
                $is_correct = 1;
            }else{
                $is_correct = 0;
            }
        
            //Second Query for Choices Table
            $query = "INSERT INTO options (";
            $query .= "question_number,choice,correct,mark)";
            $query .= " VALUES (";
            $query .=  "'{$question_number}','{$value}','{$is_correct}','{$option_marks[$counter]}'";
            $query .= ")";

            $counter++;
```